# What's the deadline for Democratic party primaries candidates for meeting the new debate criteria?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, democratic-party, democratic-primary

It seems the DNC has [tightened the criteria](https://www.npr.org/2019/05/29/727852195/democratic-presidential-field-will-look-a-lot-smaller-by-september) for people to appear in the September debates. But - how long do the candidates have to meet the criteria? Do they need to meet it now already?

Comment: While that article is relatively objective (and the article is correct), the source doesn't look like the best.

Comment: @Obie2.0: Ok, so, apparently I didn't understand your comment. What were you saying about the source?

Comment: The information is correct, but the source looks less than objective and wouldn't be something I'd cite when there are others. I thought that was clear from the first comment.

Comment: @Obie2.0: It came up on a search and has nice pictures of donkeys :-)

Comment: The first result (or one of the first) in your search for news about democratic debate rules changes was a fairly obscure site?

Comment: [It's not that far-fetched](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=DNC+requirements+democratic+debates). But TBH I heard those keyword in that order elsewhere.

Comment: Anyway, signs of their lack of objectivity, that is mixing news and opinion, include the graphic (the in their words, "symbolically red" donkeys, presumably intended to represent Communism or that the Democrats are no different from Republicans), frequent references to the "Corporate Media" or "Big Corporate Media," some of the language in an article about Netanyahu ("the vast majority of Anericans who support Israel") and the rest.

Comment: Or little turns of phrase like these in an article about a Saudi Prince that they qualify as a "Trump-Hater": "A whopping 15 of the 19 hijackers were Saudis", "Worth noting, the Kingdom of Saudi Arabia did not and is not allowing any Muslim refugees into their country", "But his “America First” platform was a direct threat to the less reputable members of the Saudi royal family."

Comment: @Obie2.0: I have not made any positive claims about that website. It seems to bother you so I'll switch to the NPR source.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94886/discussion-between-obie-2-0-and-einpoklum).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two criteria that need to be met in order to qualify for the September 12/13 debates.

**Polling:** Candidates must achieve at least 2% in at least four qualifying polls, released between June 28 and August 28.

**Fundraising:** Candidates must receive donations from at least 130,000 unique donors, including at least 400 unique donors from each of 20 different states, by the end of the day on August 28.

No candidates will be able to qualify for another couple of weeks because of the first rule.

Source: [DNC Press Release, May 29](https://democrats.org/press/third-debate/)